# Send an email when a pipeline fails in Data fusion

Tags: pipeline, google-cloud-data-fusion

I need when a pipeline fails the data merge to create a table inside bigquery that says it failed or send me a mail. How could I achieve it? I know I can use a condition, but I need to capture the failure event. Does anyone have an idea how to do it?

[The following pipeline validates if the input data is equal to the output data and if it is true it stores a table in bigquery with 1 if it is true or with 0 if it is not. What I need is also to save data in bigquery when the pipeline fails.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Kste.png)